# How do I get a favicon to display with out a server?

Tags: xhtml, favicon, ico

I am doing client side testing for my web application using IE only, there is no server - so I can test my CSS/XHTML/Javascript.

When I add the line

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon1.ico"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="icon"href="favicon1.ico"type="image/x-icon"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"href="favicon1.ico"type="image/x-icon"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"href="file://favicon1.ico"type="image/x-icon"/>
```

I do not see my .ico image displayed in the tab.

My favicon1.ico is a 32px by 32px (32 bpp, 8-bit alpha, no pallete) .ico file created/saved in GIMP residing in the same directory as my html files.

Pretty convinced IE needs a server at this point.  I'm trying somewhat random things and using trial and error.  Is there a good documentation point for this?

This is temp fix per selected answer.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAoCAYAAAD+MdrbAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dEAP8A/wD/oL2nkwAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9sHBRUfKj3fzL0AAAAdaVRYdENvbW1lbnQAAAAAAENyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBHSU1QZC5lBwAAAFVJREFUSMftzEEKACAIRFHrZHX/Q9kmKKJS013zYXbDS0TMFFim4AACBAgQIECAAH8Ea58mZmFl+hb5r8a0qAnToGZMQp+wG/qMnVAXtkPd2IqGYANt44KonPpHX24AAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
```

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Pretty sure the favicon only displays over http(s). Why not just install a simple server?

Comment: @Jess - Not in Chrome.  @Giraffe - It so far appears so.  I wanted to understand how it works, but it might be more effort then it's worth with out documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a data URI; convert an image using an online service [like this one](http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/) and use that for the href value.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
```

Comment: This usually will raise the file size of your document, but reduce the amount of HTTP requests. It's only recommended you do this if you only have a small number of pages. If you're using this same favicon and more than about 3 or 4 pages, you should link to it.

Comment: In addition to Michael Irigoyen's comment, another reason to have a separate file is because many browsers request yourdomain.com/favicon.ico file without being directed to do that. So it's worthwhile to follow this ancient convention and at least have the file in place at the root folder of your web server.

Comment: Now, no one here actually addressed why the icon is not showing up on your server.  First of all, the correct format should be `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>`. The only reasons your example in the OP might not work is that either your server is missing mimetype configuration for ico files, or because the path is not root-relative (`href="/favicon.ico"` instead of just `href="favicon.ico"` and your HTML document was not in the right folder and the file wasn't present.

Comment: FWIW, OP says "there is no server" ;-)

Comment: I've tried using your approach in an application I'm working on - can you take a look at my answer and see why it might not be working?

Comment: Another [data URI generator](https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php) in case the one linked about doesn't work (it didn't for me).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to write an embedded application that serves it own web pages, and I'd like to get this working.  However, I think I'm formatting the response incorrectly.  Why is this not generating a fav icon in my browser tab (I'm guessing wrong Content-type or something similar):

```
curl -v localhost:7777/favicon.ico
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7777 (#0)
> GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7777
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 1958
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhIAAgAOf/ADEzMDo0LjY2O9oNHS09P101P1c4NTBCR2A3KHQwO8QaK4otL88aJWw3LL4gJL4gKcAhH5osMT1HO8khKdIeLURGQ9wcJssiJCpOYNUhKVxEQ94gLklLSFNJTENOTnFIGk5ORsAvLWFLPmVLNcwwMzpYZrY3QURWYIBJPT1bUideeoJITU5VZ1pWVVtVXyJjhFxbU0xhSWVaStQ7PVtcZT1oTRlskkNjfAB1psJHOzJxR5tVTWplZLdSQGNndAB+tRqEPXBpUXJnaACBvllxXR6FRppgU1B5V1V5TMdYRGtwZwCGzMxXSySLQ8pYXF51hdZXUrNjWHd2XFmCYGOAZTmGpziQSS+TSn14ceFdWT6PT85kU4J7URePxzaSURqOzESOWrdtXjeWRzqZSb1vbaF/KJZ7elOSZclxXDSfTlGMtk6WXCyVzaKBONxsYchxbTiTxXiJdyaY1mmQZ0GfT0WUwkagSkCiWNl2ZD6nVV2eZEumUWecbWWeZcWAdDqg0kmqTF6iYVuZz0Ohx0esU3WaflWoWU6h3O9+d1CxUnCkdlOwWJudU0y1TpCbis+JhtuHeu2CeFil2pybd32kel6k4NeKgIGjiPODgFi1Y1q5WauhY2ur3G61c2K8Y2a7bbKgn5WskZKujG6y2/KUg7WnfG/AaMykmdyhirCrqXjDcs2vPpa2nc2yJdikkZ63kIjBg4bDe4G65cy1Spm+jtS4Nqa8nuWrnZC+5dS2b43Jhda6RZjEntS7Vcy8Z9u/NN6/NdG8gMLDh+HEMLLFsd/EQcXEldvFZ5vM5uLIUKHUmejKN7POstTIkq3RrOrML9rOeqfZpfDQKKjZq/TDuuvGvO7UK57Z8dzQlvHWIObPi+zUXMfXveHSpu3XU9jXlPbbJvTbR7fiuOLYpOrZg/vfHt/dk+ban/bhLeTZuPzgLvnjIMrixvXmIvziQPnlPObgsfTlV/nmR/XoR/rnUePkufvnYvnoafnocfbqfPHouvPsw//vqP/yt//2mJCRlCH+EUNyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAP8ALAAAAAAgACAAAAj+AP8JHEiwoMGDCBMqXMiwoUOC1W6hQnWr2kOE1Pyg2cIkSZItW9A8snhR4KkeeB48cLByZYgQOd6ULCQCCgkGOC9cYEBhggIFEEw8hDUF1IwMGSZAiRTJTQgKGSxcmPCgIaxolFLNGJAFkpEVKHZYQnTBAgWpThby8jQtWpxHWfwUoPHEhwsDYUhZiLphgCuFnRZ9ikULFJkOL+ocEqRmCIsomDZItsAkITNDhDSp0uXIjIo/h0bJ4iSnSwcECRZEeDCjG0JFezKb0sUMho0uknBdkyVp0A1jpbjI0NCgDUI9dPYk8qSLV4XbuZHJkgPnxCZ86ML5GvEBYaAxdBL+aXYmQcUSOZxGVZJT5cAme+vKZStWxvsVOoCWs4vhwcaSL2x88UMJAYwzzzrgSPNMLcd5MYYdhDSizCUVpPACDj/ggIEAQfTTTjnoPDNMLfAcBMYVVqRBSCKLiBOHBAIQcAABAIAAzz3xWbNgKwiBocUVYtgR2yfiXKJECxVwIMU++cSX4DK1rPLaGk1YIQYdeRCSyStYYFGPPvzg42Q20oyYC0LcrFFEE1dckcYdc/AwiT/53CMPOuWUA441I86STkJ8rAEEm2JQIYQw+NhDz51OKvjLLr4oZMsZWgBRBBFYmHNPPPS8o8468WVjzaO9NLMQK31YUUQF38Qjjzxa74CKIJnAFFNqQ6HooYUOk8zjDjrqlDOriMn0EsxDtvDBRw2MxLqOOjouk0wyx2BTEjGiUHIEI/G4E44322xzDDQlliQQN6xcgoQw5JCjzTnmxivvvPTWW1JAADs=" />
```